# Alamofire Image blurry Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am resizing an image in a tableView cell and it is comming up very blurry.

```
let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter(size: imageView.frame.size)
messageImage.af_setImage(withURL: messageImageDownloadUrl! as URL, filter: filter, imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.2))
```

How can I fix the blur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be mixing both an `AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter` and a contentMode of `AspectFill` together. You also shouldn't need to `ClipToBounds`. I'd recommend setting the contentMode to `.Center`.